# find the minimum value of $N$ given that $N$ is a positive integer and $N=3a^2-ab^2-2b-4$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

### Question:

Find the minimum value of $N$ given that $N$ is a positive integer and $N=3a^2-ab^2-2b-4$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$

---

### My attempt:

By a bit of guessing and checking I was able to obtain $N=2$ for $a=4$ and $b=3$ but I am unable to prove that $N$ is not equal to $1$ therefore I am looking for a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose for some $a, b$ we have $N = 1$. That is, $3a^2 - b^2a - (2b + 5) = 0$, viewed as a quadratic equation of $a$.

Taking determinant, we get $b^4 + 24b + 60$, which must be a perfect square. Since it's strictly larger than $(b^2)^2$, it must be at least $(b^2 + 1)^2$.

Thus we have $(b^2 + 1)^2 \le b^4 + 24b + 60$, which leads to $2b^2 - 24b - 59 \le 0$, and therefore $b \le 14$.

Checking all $b$ from $1$ to $14$, none of them gives $b^4 + 24b + 60$ a perfect square. Therefore no positive integers $(a, b)$ would give $N = 1$.

Comment: +1 Smooth approach. Note that you even have 
$$b^2+24b+60\geq(b^2+2)^2,$$
because the discriminant is congruent to $b^4$ mod $2$. This leads to
$$b^2-6b-14\leq0,$$
which gives you $b\leq7$.

Comment: @Servaes Yes, that's more clever.

Comment: Also, if $b$ is odd then
$$b^4+24b+60\equiv5\pmod{8},$$
so this cannot be a perfect square. Then it remains to check $b\in\{2,4,6\}$.